# Laravel - Allowing Authenticated and Non Authenticated users to post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm wondering if someone could shed some light on an issue im having.

I am following a tutorial on Laracasts about building a forum using Laravel ( 5.4 ) and TDD.

At the moment we have developed the authentication system and now its moving on to actually posting a 'thread'.

In the tutorial, only logged in users can post, then the post is associated with the user that posted it.

But, how would i go about allowing non-logged in users to post as well.

What would be the best approach to take to this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us at least the link of the tutorial to check what you have done so far ?

Comment: Make the `user_id` field in you post table nullable?

Comment: @BenjaminBrasseur This is a link to the episode https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel/episodes/6

Comment: @Jerodev thats an interesting idea ... Has this worked for you before and would there be any downside to the doing this while using TDD?

Answer (score 3):

Solution, maybe not good : Create anonymous user in your users table (with ID = 0 for example). And after if user is not logged in to post a thread, you use anonymous user, and you store IP address in your thread table.

Storing IP Address will permit you to attribute thread when user will decide to create his account (and replace 0 by the real user_id in the futur)

Comment: Interesting ... But is it possible to have a primary auto_increment id value of 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Provides an authentication which can be injected in the constructor of your controller .

Check this link for your reference 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication

or Since your watching Laracast what the Laravel from Scratch the part where jeffrey is creating a Blog

Good Luck